# How can we integrate a function for surface area of revolution?

Tags: integration, geometry, area

[image: Surface Area of Quadratic]

This is the equation (with my values plugged in) for surface area of revolution which I found online and I understand the derivation, thus I wanted to use it for a math project I am currently working on. I attempted to use the quadratic function (outside the radical) and inside the radical is the first derivative squared. However, I am stuck in evaluating the integral. I tried u substitution where u is equal to -1/12x+2/3 but was unable to finish it.

Is trigonometry required and does the u substitution I attempted not work in this case? What is the Surface area (answer to the integral)?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried u-sub with $u=(-\frac{1}{24}x^2+\frac{2}{3}x)$?

edit: I just realized you made these values up. My suggestion may be wrong, but I'm curious to see if this is integrable because I can't think of anything.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$\begin{aligned}
S &= 2 \pi \int_0^8 \left( \frac{2}{3} x - \frac{1}{12} x^2 \right) \sqrt{1 + \left( \frac{2}{3} - \frac{1}{12} x \right)^2 } \, d x \\
~ &= \frac{2 \pi}{12} \int_0^8 \left( 8 x - x^2 \right) \sqrt{1 + \left( \frac{2}{3} - \frac{1}{12} x \right)^2 } \, d x \\
~ &= \frac{2 \pi}{12} \int_0^8 \left( 8 x - x^2 \right) \sqrt{\frac{1}{12^2} \left( x^2 - 16 x + 208 \right) } \, d x \\
~ &= \frac{2 \pi}{12^2} \int_0^8 \left( 8 x - x^2 \right) \sqrt{x^2 - 16 x + 208 } \, d x \\
~ &= \frac{\pi}{72} \int_0^8 x ( 8 - x ) \sqrt{12^2 + (8 - x)^2} \, d x \\
\end{aligned}$$
and with $y = 8 - x$, noting that $d y = - d x$, but we also need to swap the integration boundaries, so we get
$$\begin{aligned}
S &= -\frac{\pi}{72} \int_8^0 ( 8 - y ) y \sqrt{12^2 + y^2} \, d y \\
~ &= \frac{\pi}{72} \int_0^8 \left( 8 y - y^2 \right) \sqrt{12^2 + y^2} \, d y \\
\end{aligned}$$
I would continue by integration by parts, via
$$\begin{aligned}
S &= \frac{\pi}{72} \int_0^8 f(y) \, g(y) \, d y \\
f(y) &= 8 y - y^2 \\
g(y) &= \sqrt{12^2 + y^2} \\
\end{aligned}$$
The exact result is
$$\begin{aligned}
S &= 36 \pi \log\left(\frac{2}{3} + \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^2} \right) + \frac{\pi \, 424 \, \sqrt{13}}{27} - 64\pi \\
~ &= 36 \pi \log\left(\frac{2}{3} + \frac{\sqrt{13}}{3} \right) + \frac{\pi \, 424 \, \sqrt{13}}{27} - 64\pi \\
~ &= 36 \pi \operatorname{asinh}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right) + \frac{\pi \, 424 \, \sqrt{13}}{27} - 64\pi \\
~ &\approx 47.519 \\
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: I think your method is pretty good. I also thought of another way because the integral is so hard to compute could you do this question accurately with Riemann Sums?

Comment: @thampel1: *Numerically* the integral is trivial to compute with any sort of computer program (since it is of a smooth function with a single maximum and zeros at integration boundaries, and monotonic between the zeros and the maximum), and computer algebra systems like Maxima, Maple, Mathematics – even [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+pi%2F72*x*%288-x%29*sqrt%2812%5E2%2Bx%5E2%29+from+x%3D0+to+8) – can solve it just fine.  I know there are other ways this integral could be evaluated, but alas, my math-fu is not strong enough to know them.  Apologies!